# Is it possible to define /home's sub folders physical location (SDD vs HDD) if the /home folder spans 2 physical volumes?

Tags: fedora, lvm, hard-disk, ssd

I have just installed Fedora on my laptop. I have 2 drives: SSD and HDD. I let Fedora to install Linux in both disks and decide the partitions by itself.

This is how Fedora has created and setup the logical volumes (`$ sudo lvs -o lv_uuid,lv_full_name,lv_path,lv_size,seg_pe_ranges,seg_size --units h`):

[image]

Below image (`$ sudo lvs -o +devices /dev/mapper/fedora_localhost--live-home`) shows that the `/home` folder is split in both drives, SSD and HDD:

[image]

I would like to know if it is possible to select the physical location of each folder, for example, `Videos` on the HDD (`sdb3`), `Nextcloud` on the SSD (`sda3`), etc.

[image]

Sorry if I'm making a dumb question, I'm new to Linux and this is my first time with LVM. If it is not possible to decide the location of each folder now, what can I do? Should I reinstall and define the partitions manually during Fedora installation process? Any advice or guide on how to do it to accomplish what I need?

Your help will be much appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the site.  One rule we have is using text blocks instead of screenshots of console commands.

Comment: Thanks @Stewart! . I used screenshots to show command outputs, the commands were added as inline code snippets. Is there a rule explaining how to post command results? I guess adding them as text might make the whole post difficult to read ... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot assign directories to physical volumes (PVs) or physical extends (PEs).

Since you don't have any data yet, the easiest way to go would be to re-install Fedora. Yet if you want to experiment with lvm and filesystems, it's possible to shrink LV `home` and then remove one of the two PVs from it. But, a caveat is that XFS filesystem cannot be shrinked and I suppose that since you let defaut options, XFS must have been used. So you have to backup `/home`, delete filesystem of `home` LV, shrink LV, remove PV from VG. Then format (the shrank) LV `home` using xfs or ext4 (or any other filesystem you like, Linux has many choices available) and restore data.

Also have in mind that in Unices a disk can be assigned to a mount point. That's a concept of the original UNIX, predating LVM. So for example, you could have the Fedora installer use only the 1st disk, sda, assigned to LVM or whatever. After the OS is installed, you could make a subdirectory, for example `/home/second-disk` and mount the 2nd disk there. No LVM needed for that. So in a way, you can achieve what you asked for, but it's not very flexible.

If you are to going to re-install the OS, make a plan beforehand on what you want to go where. LVM is very flexible, extending a file system is easy, shrinking is not - on XFS not possible at all.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I find LVM really interesting, will try to play with it. I will reinstall the OS in the SSD disk as suggested and use symlinks to the HDD for the folders I don't need to have fast access (Videos, Docs, etc.). It is a very common to have SSD+HDD combos these days, it would be nice to have a tool to plan the partition scheme during installation.